# Get radius of a SCNSphere that is used to create a SCNNode

Tags: swift, scenekit, scnnode

How do i return the radius of a sphere geometry(SCNSphere) used to set up a SCNNode.
I want to use the radius in a method where i move some child nodes in relation to a parent node. The code below fails since radius appears to be unknown to the resulting node, should i not pass the node to the method?

Also my array index fails saying that Int is not a Range.

I am trying to build something from [this](http://www.weheartswift.com/introduction-scenekit-part-1/)

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class PrimitivesScene: SCNScene {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.addSpheres();
    }

    func addSpheres() {
        let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1.0)
        sphereGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
        let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
        self.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

        let secondSphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.5)
        secondSphereGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.greenColor()
        let secondSphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: secondSphereGeometry)
        secondSphereNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 1.25, z: 0.0)

        self.rootNode.addChildNode(secondSphereNode)
        self.attachChildrenWithAngle(sphereNode, children:[secondSphereNode, sphereNode], angle:20)
    }

    func attachChildrenWithAngle(parent: SCNNode, children:[SCNNode], angle:Int) {
        let parentRadius = parent.geometry.radius //This fails cause geometry does not know radius.

        for var index = 0; index < 3; ++index{
            children[index].position=SCNVector3(x:Float(index),y:parentRadius+children[index].radius/2, z:0);// fails saying int is not convertible to range.
        }


    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with `radius` is that `parent.geometry` returns a `SCNGeometry` and not an `SCNSphere`. If you need to get the `radius`, you'll need to cast `parent.geometry` to `SCNSphere` first. To be safe, it's probably best to use some optional binding and chaining to do that:

```
if let parentRadius = (parent.geometry as? SCNSphere)?.radius {
    // use parentRadius here
}
```

You'll also need to do that when accessing the `radius` on your `children` nodes. If you put all that together and clean things up a little, you get something like this:

```
func attachChildrenWithAngle(parent: SCNNode, children:[SCNNode], angle:Int) {
    if let parentRadius = (parent.geometry as? SCNSphere)?.radius {
        for var index = 0; index < 3; ++index{
            let child = children[index]
            if let childRadius = (child.geometry as? SCNSphere)?.radius {
                let radius = parentRadius + childRadius / 2.0
                child.position = SCNVector3(x:CGFloat(index), y:radius, z:0.0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note though that you're calling `attachChildrenWithAngle` with an array of 2 children:

```
self.attachChildrenWithAngle(sphereNode, children:[secondSphereNode, sphereNode], angle:20)
```

If you do that, you're going to get a runtime crash in that `for` loop when accessing the 3rd element. You'll either need to pass an array with 3 children every time you call that function, or change the logic in that `for` loop.

Comment: Yes! This can also be used to change the radius of existing nodes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I'm only working with spheres, hence the radius is quite easy to manipulate. But still, I think you should try to look at the **geometry of the SCNNode**. I use this function besides the code snippet you posted (the two works together just fine for me).

```
func updateRadiusOfNode(_ node: SCNNode, to radius: CGFloat) {
    if let sphere = (node.geometry as? SCNSphere) {
        if (sphere.radius != radius) {
            sphere.radius = radius
        }
    }
}
```

Also the scaling factor (at the radius) is also important. I use a baseRadius then i'm multiplying that with

```
maxDistanceObserved / 2
```

Always updating the max distance if a hitTest has futher results.